Features of a linear minimisation problem
Let $\Delta$ be the set of all possible functions    $\mu: X\rightarrow [0,1]$ such that $X$ is a finite set and $\sum_{x\in X}\mu(x)=1$.  Let $u: Y\times X\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, where $Y$ is a finite set.
Given $x\in X$ and $y\in Y$, consider the following linear minimisation problem:
$$
\begin{aligned}
& (1) \quad  \min_{\mu\in \Delta} \mu(x)\\
& \text{ s.t. } \sum_{x\in X} \mu(x) [u(y,x)-u(y',x)]\geq 0 \quad \forall y'\in Y
\end{aligned}
$$
Question:

I am interested in computing, for each $x\in X$ and $y\in Y$,   $A(x,y)\equiv \min_{\mu\in \Delta} \mu(x) \text{ s.t. } \sum_{x\in X} \mu(x) [u(y,x)-u(y',x)]\geq 0 \text{ } \forall y'\in Y$. Without further assumptions, should I solve (1) for each $x\in X$ and $y\in Y$, or is there some simplifications I can implement?

Given $x\in X$ and $y\in Y$, let $B(x,y)\equiv \max_{\mu\in \Delta} \mu(x) \text{ s.t. } \sum_{x\in X} \mu(x) [u(y,x)-u(y',x)]\geq 0 \text{ } \forall y'\in Y$. Is $B(x,y)=-A(x,y)$?


